# Creating 3 children processes and exiting them after a specified number of seconds

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, child-process

image for what output is supposed to look like:[image]My problem is that I need to write a program that will accept the names of 3 processes as command-line arguments. Each of these processes will run for as many seconds as:(PID%10)*3+5 and terminate. After those 3 children terminated, the parent process
will reschedule each child. When all children have been rescheduled 3 times, the parent will terminate. I have used fork to create the three children but am struggling with getting them to exit with that specific criteria?

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i;
    int pid;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) // loop will run n times (n=3)
    {
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            pid = getpid();
            cout << "Process p" << i+1 << " pid:" << pid << " Started..." << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // loop will run n times (n=3)
    wait(NULL);

  }
```

Comment: Have you tried getting *one* child process to terminate with that condition? Or a simpler condition? What is the sticking point?

Comment: so I am stuck at simply setting the time the child process should run, im not familiar with any functions that specify a time in seconds for the process to run and then terminate

Comment: try using `sleep()` for every child before exiting it. it will pause the process for a number of seconds

Comment: I have added a link to the beginning of my post so that you can have a better idea of what I am looking to do. Perhaps I didnt describe it the best

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sigtimedwait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigtimedwait.2.html) to wait for `SIGCHLD` or timeout.

Working example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

template<class... Args>
void start_child(unsigned max_runtime_sec, Args... args) {
    // Block SIGCHLD.
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGCHLD);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, nullptr);
    // Enable SIGCHLD.
    signal(SIGCHLD, [](int){});

    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    switch(child_pid) {
    case -1:
        std::abort();
    case 0: {
        // Child process.
        execl(args..., nullptr);
        abort(); // never get here.
    }
    default: {
        // paren process.
        timespec timeout = {};
        timeout.tv_sec = max_runtime_sec;
        siginfo_t info = {};
        int rc = sigtimedwait(&set, nullptr, &timeout);
        if(SIGCHLD == rc) {
            std::printf("child %u terminated in time with return code %d.\n", static_cast<unsigned>(child_pid), info.si_status);
        }
        else {
            kill(child_pid, SIGTERM);
            sigwaitinfo(&set, &info);
            std::printf("child %u terminated on timeout with return code %d.\n", static_cast<unsigned>(child_pid), info.si_status);
        }
    }
    }
}

int main() {
    start_child(2, "/bin/sleep", "/bin/sleep", "10");
    start_child(2, "/bin/sleep", "/bin/sleep", "1");
}
```

Output:

```
child 31548 terminated on timeout with return code 15.
child 31549 terminated in time with return code 0.
```

Answer (score -1):

With these changes your program produces the desired output:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int round = 0; ++round <= 4; )
    {
        int i;
        cout << "*** ROUND: " << round << " ***\n";
        for (i=0; i<3; i++) // loop will run n times (n=3)
        {
            if (fork() == 0)
            {
                int pid = getpid();
                cout << "Process p" << i+1 << " pid:" << pid << " started...\n";
                unsigned int seconds = pid%10*3+5;
                cout << "Process " << pid << " exiting after "
                     << seconds-sleep(seconds) << " seconds\n";
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        while (i--) // loop will run n times (n=3)
        {
            int status;
            cout << "Process " << wait(&status);
            cout << " exited with status: " << status << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

- As Serge suggested, we're *using `sleep()` for every child before exiting it. it will pause the process for a number of seconds*.
- To get the actual status information, we call `wait(&status)` instead of `wait(NULL)`.
- We're doing this all for the first scheduling round plus the desired *3 times* of rescheduling.